# Esconder um elemento quando a tela estiver em um determinado pixel em Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5, javascript-eventos, html-select

Amigos, gostaria de esconder um elemento da página quando a tela estiver em um determinado pixel!
Consegui nesse formato, mas quando eu abro tela no pixel determinado, a página bre exibindo o elemento, o elemento só esconde quando eu defino o tamanho da tela arrastando com o mouse.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Teste JS</title>
    <script>
      window.onresize = function() {
        var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
        var x = document.getElementById("teste");
        if (w < 375) {
          x.style.display = "none";
        }
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="teste">
      <option value="">Teste</option>
      <option value="">Teste</option>
    </select> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia resolver isso utilizando CSS. Se por exemplo a sua DIV tiver aplicada uma classe chamada "minha_div", você poderia ocultar desta forma:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 375px) {
.minha_div{display:none;}
}
```

Comment: Funcionou amigo! muito obrigado!